# Iterate through string

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, loops, element

I am having difficulties in Ruby for an assignment(we just started to see it). I think I am close to the answer but something is not right with how I stor emy string elements.

So the assignment is to have a method `HID_Num(String)` that takes a string.

To be a valid string it needs to have:  4 uppercase letters, followed by 8 digits number (e.g.: `"ABCD18347692"`).The method should return the individual number as an integer value, or nil if no individual valid card number is found.

Ex: `HID_num` (`"ADBC12345678 abcD12345678"`) should return `12345678`
my code so far:

```
def HID_num(str)
  str.gsub(/\s+/m, ' ').strip.split(" ")
  str.each { |element|
    if(element.count == 12)
      count = str.count("A-Z")
      if(count == 4)
        count2 = str.count("1-9")
        if(count == 8)
          puts str[3...11]
        else{
            puts "nil"
        }   }
    end end
```

What'S wrong with it: does not store the element of `str.gsub`.
I was thinking to used pointers but not sure how to used them OR to store each element in an array but I have no idea how... Maybe I am thinking too much like Java coding?
Thanks!

Comment: The language used is in the tags for your question. Try and keep the title for explanations, not tagging. The code here is also a bit of a wreck, I'm not sure what happened to your indentation. Remember Ruby does not use `{ ... }` for things like `if` or `else`.

Comment: The code provided would not pass a ruby parser in the first place. Please post the real code you ran to get to the problem with `gsub` does not modify the value (which is also there.) **NB** I fixed the indentation to some extent.

Comment: What if a HID_num contains more than one match?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to do with regular expressions.  Here's an example:

```
def hid_num(str)
  exp   = /\A[a-z]{4}(\d{8})\z/i
  match = str.match(exp)
  match && match[1]&.to_i
end
```

In this case, the expression `exp` matches strings beginning with 4 alphabet characters, followed by 8 digits, to the end of the string.  Next, we grab a match on the `exp` against the provided `str`.  If there is not a match, return nil; otherwise, return the digit portion of the string, cast to an integer value.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh wow! The teacher didn't explain regular expressions at all, but it is in the textbok. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
def HID_num(string)
  entries = string.split(" ")
  entries.map do |entry|
    matches = entry.match(/\A[A-Z]{4}(\d{8})\z/)
    next unless matches
    matches[1]
  end.compact
end
```

It's a fairly simple regex matcher - this will return an array of all the valid strings' numbers. If you want to tweak it to return just the *first* valid number, you can change `map` for `each` and add `break` ahead of the line `matches[1]`, and finally remove the `compact`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think `scan` would be cleaner.